# Getting an ID of a value from dropdown list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Hey, 
I Have three IQueryable lists which i concat together into one list to be displayed in the dropdown box. But now I want to get the id of what the user selected since there are 3 lists to choose from. Thanks

Example:

```
IQueryable<Store> stores= _storeRepository.FindAll().OrderBy(c => c.Description);
        var storeList = stores.ToSelectList("StoreId", "Description", viewModel.StoreId.ToString());

        IQueryable<Product> products = _productRepository.FindAll().OrderBy(j => j.Name);
        var productList = products.ToSelectList("ProductId", "Name", viewModel.ProductId.ToString());



var viewList = storeList.Concat(productList).ToList();
viewModel.Lookups = viewList; //display in dropdown
```

Comment: Is there an ID among all three lists that is unique?

Comment: Post some code?  All list elements will have an ID.  Do you mean you want the ID of the IQueryable list?

Comment: I added a code sample of what i am asking about.

Comment: That just doesn't make sense...does it?!

Comment: I would recommend that you strongly consider alternatives that allows these to be in separate dropdowns.

Comment: the problem is that they have to be in one dropdown. How about if IDictionary was considered would that make life easier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is how i went about my problem. In my Controller File - in my Get method after the button click this is what i did:

```
        resultSummaryViewModel.Value = value;
        resultSummaryViewModel.ReportFrame = new FramedViewModel();

        if(value !="")
        {
            string viewValue = value.Substring(0, value.IndexOf("|"));
            string viewType = value.Substring(value.IndexOf("|") + 1);

            resultSummaryViewModel.ReportFrame.SourceURL =
                WebPathHelper.MapUrlFromRoot(
                    string.Format(
                        "Reporting/ResultSummary.aspx?beginDate={0}&endDate={1}&Id={2}&viewType={3}",
                        resultSummaryViewModel.BeginDate, resultSummaryViewModel.EndDate, viewValue,
                        viewType));
        }
        var viewData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        viewData.Add("Schools", "|allschools");
        viewData.Add("Classes", "|allclasses");
```

This is also connected to my display page aspx.cs which contains the actual lists i use to populate.

Answer (score 0):

if you question was i have 3 lists and the user choose one how can i know which one he chosen

**Answer** :
you give all three the same name and the value will change depend on which one the user have chosen

---

if your question was i want to send the `id` value with the selected list

Answer :

the server doesn't have any info about your html attributes

just the name attribute which maps to the action method parameter name and the value which maps to the parameter value , you can't know the id value and other attributes in the server

Example :

```
<input type="text" name="Title" id="SomeValue"/>
```

Will Map To :

```
public ActionResult Index(string Title)
```

the server will not recive id="SomeValue"

**Solution** :

What you can do is place a hidden field under every item with the value you want

Comment: Thanks for the great feedback - but  for me i specify the id of each list its the way of retrieving it is what i am more looking for. I added a code sample of what i have and maybe that will narrow down thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

instead of this way, after concatenating do this

```
  viewdata["viewList"]  = storeList.Concat(productList).ToList();
```

and view display items in dropdown like this

```
 <%= Html.DropDownList("viewlist_id", (List<SelectListItem>)ViewData["viewlist"])%>
```

now use a submit button (if want to post the data to same action else use actionlink with routvalues if redirecting to different action,I am using here submit button)

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
```

and in your action you can retrieve the posted data

```
 var dropdown_id = Request.Form["viewlist_id"];
```

this way you will get the id of selected drop down. thanks

Comment: Thank you very much! I will give this a go and see how it will work out and will let you know. Thanks

Comment: So i tried this but i have this small issue. I am forming my list in my Controller.cs file and in that i cannot really insert hyperlinks to display - i do that in the view .aspx page. Would you happen to know a way to resolve that? Thanks a million.

Answer (score 0):

So i figured out how to have the values of different lists combined into one dropdown list will still being able to access its actual value or ID without concat or union- the code is a lot if anyone is interested i will go ahead and take the time to properly post it. Other than that, thank you everyone for offer your advise and help. Thanks